# repackage dependencies and fix pom

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

My maven project has a dependency. I use a few 3rd party classes. I would like to automatically repack them into my jar and exclude the dependency from pom.xml stored in jar file.

i checked [shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)  and [jarjar plugin](http://sonatype.github.io/jarjar-maven-plugin/). none of them replaces pom in produced jar. what's the point of including dependencies' binaries if those dependencies are still listed in pom? how should i properly repack dependencies?

Comment: If it's 3rd party pom you're talking about, there's no need to alter it.

Comment: no, i ment my pom. i use e.g. StringUtils from commons-lang, i have it as a dependency in my pom. then i do `package` and i want to have that class in my jar. but i don't want to have commons-lang dependency in my jar anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Maven shade plugin has the feature you need. After running

```
mvn shade:shade
```

It generates file named *dependency-reduced-pom.xml* in your projects folder, and this file doesn't have dependencies which are already placed in jar.

This behaviour is configured via following shade-plugin options:

- [createDependencyReducedPom](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html#createDependencyReducedPom)
- [dependencyReducedPomLocation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html#dependencyReducedPomLocation)

Comment: dependencyReducedPomLocation has a bug described in the documentation. besides it creates a file somewhere under the build directory, not inside the created jar

Comment: Maven is a very inflexible for fine-tuning. I think it's the closest possible feature to you needs.

Comment: @YaroslavYermilov: Maven is infinitely flexible for fine tuning, there is ant, and tons of plugins out there, and at the end of the day, if the wheel hasn't already been invented, there is custom Maven plugins which allows you to do about anything that you can do in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the maven-dependency-plugin:

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id></id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                              <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                                <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                                <version>2.6</version>   
                              </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                            <includes>org\/apache\/commons\/lang\/StringUtils.class</includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
               </plugin>
```

And then set the dependency scope of commons-lang to provided:

```
                       <dependency>
                            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                            <version>2.6</version> 
                            <scope>provided</scope>
                       </dependency>
```

commons-lang will not be carried as a transitive dependency nor be included in the jar packaging, but StringUtils will be included in the jar.

Comment: no, that's just evil. you can't include classes from other jars, without renaming them. it causes version clashes and it's just a source of problems

Comment: Please elaborate.  You can indeed include classes from other jars without renaming them, the above example proves that.  Whether it is a good practice depends entirely on the architecture of the situation.  In your particular situation, it may well be a potential source of problems, but without specifying the problem in more detail, it is impossible to determine this.  There are many cases when the suggested answer that I proposed causes no version clashes and is not a source of problems.  Please remember, this may be useful to others.

Comment: My problem was a little different than OP (obviously), but your answer was 100% the solution for me. Thanks.